# Tools to migrate table structure from MySQL to SQLServer?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

Like the title says, I just need something to migrate a set of tables from MySQL to SQLServer. I know it can't be 1-to-1, but if it'll get me as close as possible, I'll be happy.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/migrate-mysql-to-mssql.aspx

Comment: That just explains migrating the data, not the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Microsoft offers a tool called "SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL". It's available [for download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14280) free of charge (though you have to give them your name and stuff to register it). You may have to do a little tweaking (I did), but it'll get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: Logon    Link does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way to do this would be:**

First you have to download the Mysql connector for dotnet from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). Then make sure you install it.

The second step would be to download Mysql GUI tools from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html). Install the GUI tools.

Then open Mysql Workbench or Mysql Administrator and just find the option to "Backup" a database/schema. This backup will create sql scripts which you will save on your disk.

*After you have got the script there are multiple ways to do it. You can import that sql script file through command line through the sqlcmd command or you can enter it directly in visual studio or you can use any T-sql editor/parser/client to do the job.

Next you download sqlserver management studio from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985). Then you can create a new database from the left pane and then right-click on that new database and goto Tasks and then Import and then a wizard will open. From there (if you have installed the ODBC/NET connector) you will be asked for a DataSource and then you can choose MYsql provider from that list and you can move forward as the wizard directs.

That in-short was a visual/easy way to do the thing.

*One more thing to add for the direct method of migrating MYSQL to MSSQL is mentioned above, for a ODBC based direct migration method [view this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx) or [Download Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14280)

- The vice-versa of this process i.e for the migration of MSSQL to MYSQL use Mysql WORKBENCH [view this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html)

Comment: This only works in the simplest of cases (if even then). MySQL's SQL syntax is different than T-SQL's.

Comment: I mentioned the answer as being a very simple approach. It works, you have to just select out standard SQL statement from the .sql file, because it contains other directives for the Mysql engine like table engine(innodb,myisam etc). So just copy carefully the CREATE and INSERT commands and leave out rest of the stuff in there and then execute it., it'll do fine

Comment: Unless you have relationships in your RELATIONAL DATABASE, or auto incrementing fields, or types that aren't supported (e.g. blobs), or...........

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.swissql.com/ which can help you out in this.

**Extract from that site:**

> SwisSQL is a automated database migration solution that has more than
>   300+ customers. SwisSQL offers productive database migration tools for
>   stored procedure migration, SQL migration, and data migration. It
>   offers comprehensive migration solution across a wide range of
>   databases such as Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2 UDB, Teradata, Netezza,
>   Sybase ASE, MySQL, Informix, and PostgreSQL.

Approx 6 yrs back I wrote a short review about this tool here - http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2006/05/product-review-swissql-sqlone-console.html

Comment: That thing didn't understand almost any of the create table queries I threw at it.

Comment: The link does not work anymore.